Projective Representation Theory of Order 16 Nonabelian Groups
I'm currently trying to find a reference on the highest degree of any irreducible faithful projective representation of the nonabelian groups of order 16, and so far have only found that $D_8$ has a maximal degree of $2$ for such a thing.
Namely, I am suspect that there are no irreducible faithful projective representations of degree 4 or higher for any nonabelian group of order $16$, but I'm not sure. Would anyone happen to have a reference where I can find the answer to this question?

According to a computer calculation (in Magma) that I just did, the two groups
$$\mathtt{SmallGroup}(16,3) = \langle x,y,z \mid x^4=y^2=z^2=1,yz=zy,y^x=yz,z^x=z \rangle$$
and
$$\mathtt{SmallGroup}(16,11) = D_8 \times C_2$$
both have irreducible projective representations of dimension $4$.
For the first of these we can take the rational representation
$$x \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}0&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right),\ y \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\end{array}\right),\ z \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$

Thanks!  Would there be a way for me to easily check if this is faithful, and moreover if the image of all 16 resulting unitary matricies are linearly independent?

So I've verified manually this is faithful, but I suppose I need a better calculator to determine if the unitaries are infact linearly independent.  Would Magma do this?

I think I may have solved this.  Every other nonabelian metacyclic group of order $16$ with the exception of $Q_{16}$ has a dihedral presentation: $$G = \langle a,b \: | \: a^m=b^s=e, \: ba=a^rb \rangle$$ but $s$ fails to be the least positive integer satisfying the equation $$1+r+r^2 + \dots + r^{s-1} \equiv 0 \mod{m}$$ which is equivalent to the group failing to admit an irreducible faithful projective representation.  Moreover, $Q_{16}$ is splitting simple so that it cannot be written as an internal semidirect product of it's subgroups and thus can't admit a faithful irreducible projective representation.  Finally, every non-metacyclic nonabelian group of order $16$ contains an abelian normal subgroup $N$ of order $8$, either $\mathbb{Z}_8$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, which has trivial $2$-cohomology over $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.  Hence the degree of any irreducible projective representation of $G$ (if one exists at all) must divide the index $[G:N] = 2$, implying $\deg(\pi) \leq 2$.  Thus, any faithful such representation among these (if they exist at all) must have degree $\leq 2 < 4$.

But ${\mathbb Z}_4 \times {\mathbb Z}_2$ does not have trivial 2-cohomology over ${\mathbb C}^\times$.

Ah you're right, my mistake
